# How to make a script that goes through all the .m and .h files and replaces this line of code

Tags: node.js, regex, bash, shell

I wish to make a script that recursively goes through every file with a .m or .h extension, then looks for this pattern:

`#import <React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>`

and replaces it with this:

```
#if __has_include(<React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>)
    #import <React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>
#else
    #import "ThisCanBeAnyText.h"
#endif
```

The `ThisCanBeAnyText` part is what matters the most and it can be any kind of text.

The script can either be a `bash script`, or a `node javascript script`.

Comment: in bash use the find command to get the .m and .h files. and use the  exec option with sed or awk

Comment: I'm not clear how a request for techniques (perhaps using bash), solvable by a non-interactive bash script, in a bash-tagged question in SO, was deemed off-topic. Can the mods suggest what particular "Simon says" phrase @sudoplz missed in his question that would have made it on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find ... -exec` combo can be pretty energetic. If you're going that route, coding things so that the command invoked out of `find` does some validation and error checking can be more reliable.

The following demonstrates some of that, but note that the versions of `bash` and `sed` on your platform matters: getting newline characters into the substitution pattern can sometimes be a hurdle.

This script also reinvokes itself to wrap the invocation of `sed` - a technique that's a bit on the cute side, but allows the functionality to reside in the same script.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

main() {
  if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir> <anytext>" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi

  # reinvoke this script, replacing directory name with '--',
  # then perform the invoked seds with some care.

  if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    find "$1" -type f \( -name '*.m' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec "$0" -- "$2" {} +
  elif [[ "$1" = '--' ]]; then
    shift
    do_seds "$@"
  fi
}

do_seds() {
  iname="$1"
  shift

  del=$'\a'
  nl=$'\\\n'
  frm="#import <React/$iname.h>"
  to="#if __has_include(<React/$iname.h>)$nl    #import <React/$iname.h>$nl#else$nl    #import \"$iname.h\"$nl#endif"

  for file; do
    if sed "s$del^$frm\$$del$to$del" "$file" > "$file".$$; then
      if cmp -s "$file" "$file".$$; then
        # nothing changed; delete the new file
        rm -f "$file".$$
      else
        # if chmod supports --reference, retain perms that way
        chmod --reference="$file" "$file".$$
        # leave the original file around, with ~ suffix
        mv "$file" "$file"~
        mv "$file".$$ "$file"
      fi
    else
      echo "$file: failed to process" 1>&2
      rm -f "$file".$$
    fi

  done
}

main "$@"
```

For your example, if the above is saved as `do_subs` in the current directory and made executable, usage might look like:

```
$ ./do_subs directory_with_hm_files ThisCanBeAnyText
```

**Responding to Comments**

The sed "from" expression (variable `frm`) can be adjusted to include a regular expression, and the matched RE content used via back references in the "to" expression.

And if your `chmod` does not support the --reference syntax, just remove it. The new version next uses a `umask 022` instead to create publicly readable new files.

An adjusted script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

main() {
  if [[ "$#" -eq 1 ]] && [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
    # only arg is a directory, launch the find command
    find "$1" -type f \( -name '*.m' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec "$0" -- {} +
  elif [[ "$#" -ge 2 ]] && [[ "$1" = '--' ]]; then
    # two or more args, first is '--', means invoked by "find ... -exec" 
    shift
    umask 022
    do_seds "$@"
  else
    echo "Usage: $0 <dir>" 1>&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

do_seds() {
  del=$'\a'
  nl=$'\\\n'

  # adjust RE in frm pattern as needed to match real content in .h and .m files

  frm="#import <React/\\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\\)\\.h>"
  to="#if __has_include(<React/\\1.h>)$nl    #import <React/\\1.h>$nl#else$nl    #import \"\\1.h\"$nl#endif"

  for file; do
    if sed "s$del^$frm\$$del$to$del" "$file" > "$file".$$; then
      if cmp -s "$file" "$file".$$; then
        # nothing changed; delete the new file
        rm -f "$file".$$
      else
        # leave the original file around, with ~ suffix
        mv "$file" "$file"~
        mv "$file".$$ "$file"
      fi
    else
      echo "$file: failed to process" 1>&2
      rm -f "$file".$$
    fi
  done
}

main "$@"
```

Usage now becomes:

```
$ ./do_subs directory_with_hm_files
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this is awesome!!! Works like a charm.
I'll accept the answer since it saved me *hours* of headache, but if it was to be 100% perfect it would not need a second parameter as a text, and it would work with any text.

Is that super hard to do? Any ideas?

Comment: Also can we somehow get rid of the chmod `--reference` ? I commented out the chmod part to make it work in OSX

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your replacement string into a variable:

```
str="#if __has_include(<React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>)\n\t#import <React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>\n#else\n\t#import "ThisCanBeAnyText.h"\n#endif"
```

You could use both `find` and `sed`:

```
find -type f \( -name "*.m" -o -name "*.h" \) -exec sed -i "s;#import <React/ThisCanBeAnyText.h>;$str;" {} \;
```

Note that the replacement text (in the `str` variable) may not have any `;` otherwise `sed` will fail.